# How to change UITableViewCell Image to Circle in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

My code works for the most part.

- The issue I am having is the images start out as square, and change to circle when I scroll the table or refresh it.

What am I missing?

**Here's my code:**

```
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:157.0/255.0 green:34.0/255.0 blue:53.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
    .CGColor;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    NSDictionary *tweet = (self.results)[indexPath.row];
    
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    
        NSString * imageString = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.profile_image_url"];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];
        
        if (imageData != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        }
    });
```

**EDIT** ---- The code is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

- Right when I launch the app the cell images are square. If I `pullToRefresh` the change to round or if I start scrolling the table they change to round.

**EDIT TWO**

Another issue I am seeing is the images change as I scroll.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Where do you have this code?

Comment: The code you posted indicates that you want the image views to be round, correct? So the problem is that they don't appear round initially?

Comment: it's in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Yes, I want them to always be round, but they start as square and update to round if I refresh or scroll.

Comment: Every thing here depends upon the row height. So if you have row height as 100, just make the cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=50; That means always the rowHeight/2.

Comment: I get the same problem.Sometimes `UIImageView` is circle, sometimes not.But I find if your Image height and width equal to cell's height, it will work.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

In order if anyone having this problem, here is the solution in

> Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:ContactCellTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ContactCellTableViewCell



    var contact : ContactStruct
    image = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    let newImage = resizeImage(image, toTheSize: CGSizeMake(70, 70))
    var cellImageLayer: CALayer?  = cell?.imageView.layer
    cellImageLayer!.cornerRadius = 35
    cellImageLayer!.masksToBounds = true
    cell?.imageView.image = newImage


    return cell!
}
```

As you might noticed the **35** hardcode is basically half of the image size which is **70** in here.
And here is the resize function:

```
func resizeImage(image:UIImage, toTheSize size:CGSize)->UIImage{


    var scale = CGFloat(max(size.width/image.size.width,
        size.height/image.size.height))
    var width:CGFloat  = image.size.width * scale
    var height:CGFloat = image.size.height * scale;

    var rr:CGRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
    image.drawInRect(rr)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage
}
```

Note: I am using a custom cell class as below:

```
import UIKit

class ContactCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

It really took me a while to figure this one out. The images become rounded after scrolling at first, but now using this code you are going to have the rounded images inside the cell from beginning. 
Hope it helped anyone.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in   override-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // image Width(84) / 2 = 42
            cell.CellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 42.0
            cell.CellImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
         //or   

        cell.CellImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.CellImage.frame.width / 2
        cell.CellImage.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the cell's frame (and hence the imageView's frame) isn't set the very first time the cell is created. So setting the imageView's layer's `cornerRadius` based on that initial frame doesn't work. The best solution is to implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and set the layer there:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: still start as square when I implement this

Comment: What are you getting for `cell.imageView` and `cell.imageView.frame`?

Comment: cell.imageView: <UIImageView: 0xa479fe0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa47c4a0>> and cell.imageView.frame: 0.000000

Comment: when I refresh: cell.imageView: <UIImageView: 0xa5a7890; frame = (15 30; 48 48); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5a7910>> and cell.imageView.frame: 4294968343.000000

Comment: You could set a dummy image to new cells that don't yet have an image. This should initialize the `imageView` frame so the cornerRadius calculation works as expected.

Comment: I'm loading the images asynchronously. Could it be that cells near the bottom haven't gotten images yet and that's why they appear as squares until I scroll?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom cell, and add an image view (with an `IBOutlet`), sized and positioned however you want (the outlet is "iv" in my example below). Put the code to make image view round in the `awakeFromNib` method (assuming your cell is created in a nib or storyboard).

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    self.iv.layer.cornerRadius = self.iv.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    self.iv.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    self.iv.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:157.0/255.0 green:34.0/255.0 blue:53.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    self.iv.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Cell's already come with an `imageView` property. The issue so far is that the default imageView's frame isn't set until it gets an image.

Comment: @rmaddy, yeah, I'm aware that cells come with an image view property. It works the way I did it here with no image present. Also, I'm generally not a fan of setting up things that are not indexPath dependent in the table view's delegate/data source. I think those things should belong to the cell, so that's why I suggested this approach.

Comment: This works great but only if you explicitly specify a height for the `imageView` in the storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 150.0f;
    cell.ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.ImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Refer this link for more information: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/how-to-create-rounded-avatars-in-your-ios-application/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, my `UIImageView` was initially a square and would only show as circular when the `UITableViewCell` it was within was either highlighted or selected.

It was a simple fix:

**Swift 2.0**

```
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.width / 2
imgView.clipsToBounds = true
```

This was placed inside the `awakeFromNib()` for my custom `UITableViewCell`.

This is assuming `imgView` is the name of the `UIImageView` hooked up via storyboard inside this custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image view to a circle inside the `async` call where you set the image.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSString * imageString = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.profile_image_url"];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];

    if (imageData != nil)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0;
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:157.0/255.0 green:34.0/255.0 blue:53.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
.CGColor;
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation MyCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
}

// --- image view frame is empty rect inside tableView: willDisplayCell:
// +++ set cornerRadius inside layoutSubviews works. 
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // layout image view
    CGRect vfr = self.frame;
    CGRect imgvr = self.imageView.frame;
    imgvr.origin.x = 16;
    imgvr.size.width = CGRectGetHeight(vfr);
    self.imageView.frame = imgvr;

    // update corner radius
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imgvr.size.width * 0.5f;

    // layout label
    CGRect lblr = self.textLabel.frame;
    lblr.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(imgvr) + 16;
    lblr.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(vfr) - CGRectGetMaxX(imgvr) - 32;
    self.textLabel.frame = lblr;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your cell is by code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let myImageView = (cell as! MyCustomCell).myImageView
        myImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.width / 2.0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 22.0
cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score -1):

Here is a perfect and state away solution for circular image in `UITableview` Cell.
Simply modify your `UITableviewCell` (custom cell) class with below code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    imgEvent.layer.frame = (imgEvent.layer.frame).insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    imgEvent.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    imgEvent.layer.cornerRadius = (imgEvent.frame.height)/2
    imgEvent.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imgEvent.clipsToBounds = true
    imgEvent.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    imgEvent.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
  }
```

It will also helps to solve the problem of image circular only after scrolling table..(if any[image])