# Table View Doesn't load properly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I want to build a round shape profile image. And used the following code:

```
//Void func that sets the set style
func setCellStyle(){
    // set border Width
    self.profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius =     self.profileImageView.frame.size.width/2
    self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

After loading the app i have the following issue:

[image: App just after loading screenshot]

The first few cells come with the indicated red issue and the green ones come as i expected. After going up in the tableview it updates my wrong cells to the expected. I want to load this and all imageViews come as the green one!

Can someone help me?
Regards

1º Edit:

As you can see from the green indicator, i can do it circular. The problem comes in the first cells, at launch they load like the red indicator.

Storyboard screenshot: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3MBkUrHOuRSWlzTmFENGJSOFU/view?usp=sharing

HomeViewController (cellForRowAtIndexPath method) :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3MBkUrHOuRNWd2TVcyNVluVWs/view?usp=sharing

Regards!

2º edit:

Found anwser here: [How to change UITableViewCell Image to Circle in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350728/how-to-change-uitableviewcell-image-to-circle-in-uitableview)

Comment: can you specify the exact frame of your profile image view, it seems that circular shape is not achieved because of uneven frame

Comment: please share the code for your cell as well as tableviewdatasource

Comment: have you tried reloading the table in your viewDidLoad function? call reload data function explicitly.

Comment: ( self.tableView.reloadData() on ViewDidLoad )Didn't work... I've been on this issue for a day now.

Comment: for rounded view , the view width and height should be same and set ' self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width/2.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your autolayout has not configured the final frame for the profile image when you try to round the image. Try to do the rounding **after** autolayout is finished, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

*Try This for round shape profile image

```
func setCellStyle(){
  self.profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image name"];
//set round shape image
  self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius =self.profileImageView.frame.size.height /2;
}
```

Comment: I can achive circular shapes! Check the green indicator! That's done. The problems comes when you have 100 custom cells but when you first load the app the first 5 ou 4 cells come like the red indicator. But if you move the table up and down, they all update like the green indicator.